# Binding multiple tables to Winform

Tags: winforms

I have a Winform that will display columns from 2 tables.
The form will have a bindingnavigator.

The primary table on the form is a "child" of the second table.

I need the opposite of the usual Customer/Orders linkage 
where I want to scroll thru the "orders" and automatically
pull the "customer" info.

There is one common column (ID) between the 2 tables. The ID
column in the "orders" table is not unique but the ID column 
in the "customer" table is.

The primary key in the "orders" table is a composite of the ID 
column and an order# column which is unique.

I was also unable to create a foreign key relationship when
choosing the ID columns in both tables.

I get this error:
"The columns in table 'orders' do not match an existing 
primary key or UNIQUE constraint"

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you receiving the error from? A search of the message indicates that it likely from "SQL Server Management Studio".  Have you tried just coding it to load a DataSet with the two tables and add a [DataRelation}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation?view=netframework-4.8#examples) with no constraints to the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a composite key (I mean your question is indicating it), then you have to add both columns  (ID and order) in your foreign key reference. 
   When table have composite key, you can see a key symbol next to columns that are part of the primary key.
2. When you have composite key the order of creating FK is important.
   Go to keys section of table and select script of primary key as create script to clipboard (right click on primary key and choose). Paste it in new command window and then create FK with order shown in that script of primary key. (So ID and order columns need to be defined in FK in right order)